# Ruby Gems Bundle Error (think Versions Mismatch) - Trying to run Dradis framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

This question is being asked here, since coders know ruby darkness.

(FreeBSD) I ran an install on dradis port.

Executed "bundle install" from dradis directory.
Initiated Dradis DB

It complained about the version of activesupport asking for 3.0.4 while it had 3.1.1 "activated", i installed 3.0.4, no luck, then removed 3.1.1 and this is the output

Trying to run Dradis:

```
# /usr/local/etc/rc.d/dradis start
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find activesupport (= 3.1.1) amongst [RedCloth-4.2.8, RedCloth-4.2.5, abstract-1.0.0, actionmailer-3.1.1, actionmailer-3.0.4, actionpack-3.1.1, actionpack-3.0.4, activemodel-3.1.1, activemodel-3.0.4, activerecord-3.1.1, activerecord-3.0.4, activeresource-3.1.1, activeresource-3.0.4, activesupport-3.0.4, arel-2.2.1, arel-2.0.10, bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1, builder-3.0.0, builder-2.1.2, bundler-1.0.21, coffee-rails-3.1.1, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.1.2, erubis-2.7.0, erubis-2.6.6, execjs-1.2.9, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.0, jquery-rails-1.0.16, json-1.6.1, json_pure-1.6.1, mail-2.3.0, mail-2.2.19, mime-types-1.17.2, multi_json-1.0.3, polyglot-0.3.3, polyglot-0.3.2, rack-1.3.5, rack-1.2.4, rack-cache-1.1, rack-mount-0.8.3, rack-mount-0.6.14, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rack-test-0.5.7, rails-3.1.1, rails-3.0.4, railties-3.1.1, railties-3.0.4, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.11, sass-3.1.10, sass-rails-3.1.4, sprockets-2.0.3, spruz-0.2.13, sqlite3-1.3.4, sqlite3-ruby-1.3.2, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.10, tzinfo-0.3.30, uglifier-1.0.4] (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:761:in `activate_dependencies'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:758:in `activate_dependencies'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb:742:in `activate'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:209:in `try_activate'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `require'
from script/rails:5
```

Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.4'

gem 'RedCloth', '4.2.5', :require => 'redcloth'

#if !( (RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin/i) || (RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mingw/i) )
#  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
#else
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.3.2', :require => 'sqlite3'
#end

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have already lots of gems installed on your environment so bundler gets confused.  I suggest uninstalling all gems and running bundle install again.

To uninstall all gems, run:

```
gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx
```

Comment: Also, I would suggest to use rbenv or rvm for easy version management

Comment: Worked like a charm, just had to reinstall bundler and run bundle install, Daemon starts now.

You have a nice coin pickpocket skill.